# iPhone - Write to a file without collision when multiple NSURLConnection ends

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I have a CONNECT object that make HTTP calls using :

```
NSURLConnection* connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
```

In the `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection` method, I write things to a file.

I may have mutiple HTTP calls sent from multiple instances of CONNECT objects, so I suppose there is a risk that those CONNECT objects write into the file at the same time when the connection ends.

Is this correct ? If yes, how may I prevent this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one thread then there won't be any problem as the delegates will be executed on the same thread.
Delegates are executed one after another in single threaded environment. There wont be a case when your DelegateMehtod1 is accessing the file and it has paused due to DelegateMehtod2 and then DelegateMehtod2 access the file. This happens only in multiple threads not in multiple delegates with one thread

If it is multi-threaded environment then you have to synchronize your file accessing code.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) If you are running all the NSURLConnections on a single thread (most likely the main thread), then you won't have any issue with writing to a file as long as you're doing the entire write (ie. open/create, write, close) within the connectionDidFinishLoading method. This is because a single thread can only be doing one thing at a time.

2) On the design side, do you really want multiple connections to be writing to the same file?  If you're creating lots of NSURLConnections, then generally you would want to be able to record them, give them unique filenames and process them separately.  This then allows you to know how many connections you currently have in flight, cancel them, and so forth.

If you're just writing some short-lived data to a file while you're doing the processing, then perhaps use unique names for the filenames.  Basically, I'm finding it hard to think of a good reason to have lots of concurrent downloads writing to the same file on completion - but perhaps you have one!